# UICollectionView vibrancy effect between cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with 3 cells (cells' width is `self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 3`).

The collectionView is placed inside a `UIVisualEffectView` with `dark` blur effect.

I want to add a 1px vibrancy gap between every cell, I've tried:

```
let divider1 = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRect(x: self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 3, y: 0, width: 1, height: self.collectionView.frame.size.height))
divider1.effect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))

let divider2 = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRect(x: (self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 3) * 2, y: 0, width: 1, height: self.collectionView.frame.size.height))
        divider2.effect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))

self.collectionView.addSubview(divider1)
self.collectionView.addSubview(divider2)
```

but it doesn't present anything. If I set the divider's backgroundColor to a color it does work, so it's probably something with the vibrancy effect.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Try my answer from the link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976432/background-image-not-loading-on-device. Answer based on tableView.but,It will work for collectionView to..

Comment: @Joe I can't really understand what to do in my collectionView based on your tableView answer. Can you please explain a bit more using my code? Thanks :)

Comment: you have to use backgroundView for ur collectionView to achieve that effect....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Note: Tested in Swift 3

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add a background view to the collectionView
        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Set your image file here")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
        self.collectionView.backgroundView = imageView

        //To get a balance look from collectionView background
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: backgroundImage!)

        // To setup a blurView background
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = view.bounds
        imageView.addSubview(blurView)

}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Where is the vibrancy effect on your answer? Are you sure you understand what I want to achieve?

Comment: It's easy to apply vibrancy just apply vibrancy effect to the blurView.

Comment: To apply vibrancy let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect) let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect) vibrancyEffectView.frame =blurView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyEffectView)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to play with collectionView colour rather than applying vibrancy. Just my personal opinion.try this see what happened collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha:0.6). If you play with the colour values.you will find answer...

Answer (score 0):

To make it works you need to create UIVibrancyEffect using blur effect you use in your collection view.